# How to use older versions of jQuery in JSFiddle?

Tags: jquery, jsfiddle

I see that some people can select jQuery 1.4 on JSFiddle but when I try I can't find it in the drop down! Any help would be great thanks!

Comment: You can always just select no library and then use script tags to include any library you want.

Comment: It's because it is'nt there anymore, and you should'nt have to select it, as it's too old and you should use a newer version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manually include a link to any hosted version of jQuery through the "Add Resources" panel. See https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide#jquery for the full list of available versions; jQuery 1.4 is at http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.1/jquery.min.js

Versions of jQuery this old should, in general, not be used anymore.

Comment: Thanks! I was able to add the url, but how do I make JFiddle use it?

Comment: JSFiddle will use it when you add it under the "Add Resources" panel in the left sidebar.